# unable to scroll the textview in Swift

Tags: swift, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a TextView as shown below

[image]

I am not able to scroll the text view , I have added `UITextViewDelegate` in `UIViewController` class as well as set `isUserInteractionEnabled` property in `textViewDidBeginEditing`

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    textView.isEditable = false
    textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textView.isScrollEnabled = true
}
```

What did I need to do?

Also, the scrolling is enabled in attribute inspector

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This issue has occurred because the actual `UITextView's` size was more than screen size as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The real answer is that the `UITextView` needs its content **frame** height inferior to its content **size** height to be able to scroll.

In your case, the content frame height is equal to the content size, so it doesn't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the leading left, trailing, top space and bottom space to the View, but first make sure the Text View is smaller than the actual View (parent).

Answer (score 0):

It starts to get complicated when you have a UITextView on a UIView which is either a view on a UIScrollView or directly on a UIScrollview.

The best thing to do, is to give each of them their own actions when scrolling.

Firstly, make sure you have all of your delegates for EVERYTHING set.
Make sure your UITextViews are not user restricted for what they don't need to be.

What I have to do in one of my published apps is this

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
   if scrollView == textView1
   {
      // Do something if you actually want to, or just let textView1 scroll as intended
   }
   else if scrollView == textView2
   {
      // Do something if you actually want to, or just let textView2 scroll as intended
   }
   else if scrollView == zoomingScroll
   {
      // Do something if you need to or leave it
   }
   else
   {
      // Do something with all the other scrollable views if you need to
   }
}
```